# A functor(inherrited) is forbidden when using std::sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, functor

```
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

struct FileSorter{

virtual ~FileSorter(){}
    virtual bool operator()(const boost::filesystem::path& p1, const boost::filesystem::path& p2) const =0;
};

struct SortByName : public FileSorter{
    SortByName(bool ascending=true):ascending_order(ascending)
    {
    }

    virtual bool operator()(const boost::filesystem::path& p1, const boost::filesystem::path& p2) const {
        if(ascending_order)
            return p1.stem().string() < p2.stem().string();
        else
            return p1.stem().string() > p2.stem().string();
    }

protected:
    bool ascending_order;
};

class FilesList : public std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> {
public:
    FilesList(const std::string& dir, const std::string& f_regex, const FileSorter& fileSorter=SortByName()) {
        boost::regex e(f_regex, boost::regex::perl);
        boost::filesystem::path path(dir);
        if(!boost::filesystem::is_directory(path)) {
            throw std::runtime_error(path.string()+std::string(" is not a directory\n"));
        }

        for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator file(path), f_end; file!= f_end; ++file){
            if(boost::regex_match(file->path().filename().string(), e))
                this->push_back(file->path());
        }

        std::sort(this->begin(), this->end(), fileSorter);
    }
};
```

I defined a class `FileList` which do perform create a list of files which meet the regular expression(`f_regex` argument).

To sort the list, an instance of `SortBy***` struct(**inherited** from `FileSorter`)  can be passed.

The problem is `std::sort` function cannot be compiled with the code above showing the following error message.

> **/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5483:5: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘FileSorter’**

I don't understand this behavior. In my narrow knowledge, struct equipped with `operator ()` is called **functor** and it is a good way to deal with a function as an object.

And as all we know, instance of **child class** can be referred by a reference of **parent class**.

But the above example is saying differently.

What should I change to make the code work?

If I have wrong concepts about c++, please don't hesitate to scold me.

Full compile error messages are here.

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target cpp_factory
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cpp_factory.dir/libraries/src/FileLister.cpp.o
In file included from /home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/src/FileLister.cpp:5:0:
/home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h: In constructor ‘FilesList::FilesList(const string&, const string&, const FileSorter&)’:
/home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h:109:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector<boost::filesystem::path>::iterator, std::vector<boost::filesystem::path>::iterator, const FileSorter&)’
         std::sort(this->begin(), this->end(), fileSorter);
                                                         ^
/home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h:109:57: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from /home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h:11,
                 from /home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/src/FileLister.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5447:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)
     sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5447:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/src/FileLister.cpp:5:0:
/home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h:109:57: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
         std::sort(this->begin(), this->end(), fileSorter);
                                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from /home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h:11,
                 from /home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/src/FileLister.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5483:5: note: template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)
     sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5483:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::filesystem::path*, std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> >; _Compare = FileSorter]’:
/home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h:109:57:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5483:5: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘FileSorter’
In file included from /home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/src/FileLister.cpp:5:0:
/home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h:49:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘FileSorter’:
 struct FileSorter{
        ^
/home/ub1404/Application/cpp_factory/libraries/include/cpp_factory/files/FileLister.h:51:18: note:  virtual bool FileSorter::operator()(const boost::filesystem::path&, const boost::filesystem::path&) const
     virtual bool operator()(const boost::filesystem::path& p1, const boost::filesystem::path& p2) const =0;
                  ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_factory.dir/libraries/src/FileLister.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_factory.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Your code fails to build due to an undeclared `SortByExtension`.

Comment: Sorry @AmiTavory, I omitted declaration of `SortByExtension`  to downsize the question. Sorry, there was a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Most predicate in STL are passed by copy. Could you get rid of your virtual interface and use template instead ?

Comment: @JaeJunLEE You're also missing at least two `#include`s to boost libraries.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. There's a *lot* of irrelevant code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the signature, [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes its comparison object *by value*:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

So when you write:

```
std::sort(this->begin(), this->end(), fileSorter);
```

your object gets sliced, and you end up trying to instantiate a function which takes an abstract class by value, hence all the errors you end up with.

What you need to do is ensure that even though `sort` takes its comparison by value, you pass yours in by reference. Thankfully, there's an app for that! Just use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
std::sort(this->begin(), this->end(), std::ref(fileSorter));
```

---

That said, do you *really* need a polymorphic comparator? If you're just passing in different comparison function objects into the `FilesList` constructor, you should prefer to just make it a function template:

```
template <class Sorter>
FilesList(const std::string& dir, const std::string& f_regex, Sorter fileSorter) {
    // ...
    std::sort(begin(), end(), fileSorter); // now copying is fine
}
```

That way, you can just directly forward in what the user passes and avoid virtual dispatch.

Comment: Thanks, the code works well with `std::ref`, But my code will run without **c++11** , so I've tried `boost::ref` instead and it ended up with new errors.

Comment: I could use `boost::ref` in conjunction with `boost::bind`. Like this `boost::bind<bool>(boost::ref(fileSorter), _1,_2)`.

Comment: @JaeJunLEE That's because `boost::reference_wrapper` doesn't provide a call operator. Do you *really* need a polymorphic comparator? Otherwise, yeah, the `bind` solution does the equivalent to what `std::ref` did.

Comment: Yes, @Barry. Because I will define several comparators which can be passed to `FileList` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your FileSorter argument is defaulted to a SortByExtension object rather than a SortByName object. As you haven't included the source of SortByExtension, I would start by checking that function signature of SortByExtension's function call operator is

```
bool SortByExtension::operator()(const path&, const path&) const
```

If there are any differences between the base class and derived class function signatures, the derived class function won't override the base class one, and the derived class will be treated as an abstract class.